# Sources permitting converting tefillin from one shitta to another

Tags: halacha, tefilin

Over Shabbat, I had a discussion on the subject of switching tefillin between shittot, which resulted in me asking the MIT Chabad rabbi whether switching a pair of Rashi tefillin to Rabbeinu Tam was mutar. He answered that it likely was, although he did not have any sources to back it up.

Are there any sources which discuss switching the order of parshiot in a pair of tefillin from Rashi to Rabbeinu Tam, or other shittot?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9C%D7%93_%D7%93#.D7.9B_.D7.9E.D7.91 Seems problematic

Comment: @DoubleAA that anchor isn't working (for me); what on that page are you pointing out?

Comment: @msh210 MB sk 20

Comment: For those who cannot see the link.  וממילא דאסור להחליף הכיסים וכ"ש הבתים והרצועות והפרשיות משל רש"י לר"ת או איפכא. It is forbidden to change the cases, the straps or the parshios from Rashi to Rabbeinu Tam or the reverse.

Comment: That seems to make sense, because according to each shittah you would be posseling biyadayim a cheftza shel mitzvah... But what if the tefilin were already possul, and as part of the process of "fixing" you had the parshiyot switched?

Comment: DoubleAA or @sabbahillel, so why not post an answer?

Comment: @DoubleAA please see previous comment, and delete this one.

Comment: @msh210 Since DoubleAA found and quoted the citation, I would rather that he answered.

Comment: If memory serves, I think this is actually discussed in Sefer Or Zarua and also in the Teshuvot of Rabbeinu Menachem Azariah of Fano. Just spotted the Menachem Azariah of Fano reference in the quotation from the Be'er Heitev from DoubleAA.